# No property found for type in Spring custom query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to implement a custom Spring repository. I have the interface:

```
public interface RataRepositoryCustom {

        List<RataEntity> getRateFromTipoFrequenzaRimborso(String tipoFrequenzaRimborso);
            
}
```

where the RataEntity class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rata")
public class RataEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4278591894832763005L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COD_RATA")
    private Integer codRata;
    
    @Column(name = "COD_RIMBORSO")
    private String codRimborso; 
    
    @Column(name = "DATA_PROROGA")
    private String dataProroga;

    @Column(name = "PERC_CALCOLO")
    private String percCalcolo;
    
    @Column(name = "PERC_OUTSTANDING")
    private String percOutstanding;

    @Column(name = "DATA_SCADENZA")
    private Date dataScadenza;
    
    @Column(name = "IMPORTO_RATA")
    private Double importoRata; 
     
       ... getters and setters...

}
```

the implementation of it

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class RateRepositoryCustomImpl implements RataRepositoryCustom {
    
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<RataEntity> getRateFromTipoFrequenzaRimborso(String tipoFrequenzaRimborso) {
        
    StringBuilder querySql = new StringBuilder();
    querySql.append("SELECT distinct e FROM RataEntity e, RimborsoEntity r where e.codRimborso=r.codRimborso ");
    if(tipoFrequenzaRimborso.equals("Ann"))
        querySql.append("and r.freqRimborso='Annual'");
    else if (tipoFrequenzaRimborso.equals("Sem"))
        querySql.append("and r.freqRimborso='Semestral'");
    else if (tipoFrequenzaRimborso.equals("Event"))
        querySql.append("and r.freqRimborso='Ad event'");
    
    Query query =  entityManager.createQuery(querySql.toString());
    return query.getResultList();

    }

}
```

and the following repository class

```
@Repository public interface RataRepository extends JpaRepository<RataEntity, Integer>, RataRepositoryCustom {

}
```

When I run my application, I get this error:

> Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List
> it.aubay.PreliosPAN.repositories.RataRepositoryCustom.getRateFromTipoFrequenzaRimborso(java.lang.String)!
> No property getRateFromTipoFrequenzaRimborso found for type
> RataEntity!

It seems that Spring Framework tries to find a property with my method name in the Entity.
If I check the official documentation at this link

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

we have a generic example where the method name is

> void someCustomMethod(User user)

I implemented the same code on other Entity objects and Spring Framework works properly with any method name.  Only for the class of the example I have the error but I cannot understand why. Any idea?

Comment: Does your RataEntity have field named tipoFrequenzaRimborso ?

Comment: No there is not. Am I forced to create it to implement a custom query?

Comment: If you extend extend JpaRepository all you need to do is to define abstract methods, which will run queries, however this fields must exist - this framework is using reflection to find the field by name. If there is no such field, you need to implement your query.

Comment: In fact is what I try to do, implement my custom query: but it seems that even if with custom query I I can't choose the method name. Is it correct? Do I missed something in my custom query configuration? Thanks for your answers

Comment: Please add your custom query in a question, we need to check how it looks like.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: We also need RataEntity clas

Comment: I added the requested class. Thanks

Comment: Please include the package names in the sources and please remove the `@Repository` from the interface (it is only noise it doesn't add anything).

Comment: Ok, if you want to find by String tipoFrequenzaRimborso it must be included in your RataEntity class as field. RataRepositoryCustom is an interface, where you just declare methods. No implementation is needed, because JPA framework will use reflection to find String named tipoFrequenzaRimborso inside your RataEntity class. If it's not there it won't work.

Comment: I implemented the same code on others Entity object and SPRING framework works properly with any method name.  Only for the class of the example I have the error but I cannot understand why. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
The initial part of the name of the implementation class of the custom repository 

Rat**e**RepositoryCustomImpl 

is different from the name of the interface 

Rat**a**RepositoryCustom 

The correct name of the implementation class must be 

Rat**a**RepositoryCustomImpl

Regards